# Google Sheets: Convert Value in Millions/Billions to Number

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, match, number-formatting

I've copied some data from a website into a sheet that displays dollar values in millions or billions, eg $239 M, $1.23 B, etc.

How can I convert these to numeric values?

[edit] Found an Excel example, but when I tried to convert to sheets, the result is always zero:

`=IFS( RIGHT(B4,1)="M", N(SUBSTITUTE(B4," M","")),  RIGHT(B4,1)="B", N(SUBSTITUTE(B4," B","")) *1000 )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A4&"", "M"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4, "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1000000, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A4&"", "k"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4, "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1000,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A4&"", "B"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4, "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1000000000, A1:A4))))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. I wanted to be able to handle values written like either 123.4k or 123.4K, so updated the regex to: `REGEXMATCH(A1:A4&"", "[kK]")`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For complex conversions, you can create a user defined Javascript function in [Apps-Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) and use it in sheets.

Advantages:

1. It is easy to write complex functions using JavaScript.
2. You can add tests to verify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to @player0 better formula is

```
=LET(c,C6, INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(c&"", "M"), REGEXEXTRACT(c, "[-+]?(?:\d*\.*\d+)")*10000000, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(c&"", "k"), REGEXEXTRACT(c, "[-+]?(?:\d*\.*\d+)")*10000,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(c&"", "B"), REGEXEXTRACT(c, "[-+]?(?:\d*\.*\d+)")*10000000000, c)))))
```

Also, you can use named functions in Google Sheets for this.